# PHP stream_context_set_option SSL certificate as string

Tags: php, ssl, curl, pem

I've got a weird issue. Basically, I need to do this:

```
 $handle = stream_context_create();
 stream_context_set_option($handle , 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/tmp/cert');
```

However. The certificate is not held as a file within the server. Rather it's an encrypted string held in a clustered database environment. So instead of the certificate being a file name pointer, its the physical content of the certificate. So instead of using the file name, I need to specify the content of the certificate instead.

For example:

```
 $cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----....
 upWbwmdMd61SjNCdtOpZcNW3YmzuT96Fr7GUPiDQ
 -----END CERTIFICATE-----';
```

Does anyone have any idea whatsoever how on earth I can do this? I'm scratching my head over this problem, but my gut instinct says it is doable.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Did you consider writing it to a temp file, passing the name as the parameter, then removing the file?

Comment: I'm very seriously considering it, but specifically wondering if this can be done without physically having the file stored (even temporarily) on the disk in an decrypted state. This may unfortunately be the only way to do it.

Comment: I think the temp file the only way; I checked the PHP source and when you specify `local_cert` it ultimately calls the OpenSSL function [SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file) which reads a file from the file-system.  There doesn't appear to be a way to specify the key in memory with PHP.

Comment: Thank you to Maerlyn and drew010 I'm quite happy to accept one of your comments as the right answer if you submit it as one.  Again, seriously, thank you :)

Comment: @drew010 deserves the credit, for looking into the source.

Comment: Fair enough, from my side you're both right though. Thanks on a personal level Maerlyn

Comment: @RogerThomas I added it as an answer and linked to the relevant PHP source.  But as you will see, PHP first tries to resolve the path to the full physical location on disk prior to calling the OpenSSL function that reads the cert from disk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Maerlyn said, it appears the only way to do this will be to write the certificate from memory to a temporary file, call the function, make the request, and then remove the temp file.

I looked at the PHP source code (relevant code [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/openssl/openssl.c#4486)) and when you make a request that will use SSL, it checks to see if `local_cert` context option is set, and if so, ultimately calls the OpenSSL function [SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_ctx_use_privatekey_file) which reads the certificate from a disk file.

Take note that the file doesn't get read until the request is performed, so you can't delete the temp file until after your request, as opposed to after calling `stream_context_set_option`.

Answer (score 6):

I tried to use stream_wrapper (php://memory & custom stream wrapper) with no success :-(. At least, you can create a random temp file, register it to be deleted on shutdown, then run you code

```
$tmp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "key");
register_shutdown_function("unlink",  $tmp_file);

//rest of your code go there
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's probably the best idea, but still I'd love to see PHP allow a more direct injection. It's things like this that kind of frustrate me. Nevertheless, thank you :)