# Use a PEM string as client certificate for PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, soap

I want to connect to a WS service using a client certificate.
The common way is:

```
$options = array(
'location'      => $location_url,
'local_cert'    => $certificato_ssl,
'passphrase'    => $passphrase,
'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(array('ssl'=> array(
               'verify_peer'=>false,
               'verify_peer_name'=>false,
               'allow_self_signed' => true
          )))
);
$client       = new \SoapClient($wdsl_url, $options);
```

Is there any way to pass the certificate as **PEM string and not as a local file path**?

Comment: Is there any reason why not wanting to use a file (even if it's a temporary one)?

Comment: Because I don't have it as file but as blob in database and I don't link the temp file approach if another solution exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403253/php-stream-context-set-option-ssl-certificate-as-string